# How to write unit test case for mixins in flutter?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

> Here is My mixins class

```
mixin AppCloser {
    void closeApp() {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        exit(0);
      }
    }
  }
```

> What I tried here:

```
void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  test('Test closeApp method', () {
    // Mock the SystemNavigator.pop method
    const MethodChannel methodChannel = MethodChannel('SystemNavigator');
    final List<MethodCall> log = <MethodCall>[];
    methodChannel.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
      log.add(methodCall);
    });

    // Determine the expected method call based on the platform
    final expectedMethodCall = defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
        ? 'pop'
        : 'SystemNavigator.pop';

    // Create a class that uses the AppCloser mixin
    final testClass = TestClassWithAppCloser();

    // Call the closeApp method
    testClass.closeApp();

    // Verify that the appropriate method was called based on the platform
    expect(log, <Matcher>[
      isMethodCall(expectedMethodCall, arguments: null),
    ]);
  });
}

// Create a test class that uses the mixin
class TestClassWithAppCloser with AppCloser {}
```

> Output

```
package:matcher                                     expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 454:18  expect
test/utils/mixins_test.dart 28:5                    main.<fn>

Expected: [<has method name: 'pop' with arguments: <null>>]
  Actual: []
   Which: at location [0] is [] which shorter than expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MethodChannel.setMockMethodCallHandler` is for testing *method channels* used by Flutter plug-ins.  It is not for creating mocks to arbitrary Dart functions or methods.

You cannot test your code this way (and the problem you are encountering has nothing to do with `mixin`s; you'd have the same problem if it were an ordinary class).  The class (or `mixin`) being tested needs to go through a level of indirection so that you can detect (and possibly intercept) what your class calls.  For example, something like:

```dart
void Function() systemNavigatorPop = SystemNavigator.pop;
void Function(int) myExit = exit;

mixin AppCloser {
  void closeApp() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      systemNavigatorPop();
     } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      myExit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

and then in your test:

```dart
void main() {
  test('Test closeApp method', () {
    var log = <String>[];
    systemNavigatorPop = () => log.add('SystemNavigator.pop()');
    myExit = (exitCode) => log.add('exit($exitCode)');

    var testClass = TestClassWithAppCloser();
    testClass.closeApp();
    expect(
      log,
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
        ? ['SystemNavigator.pop()']
        : ['exit(0)'],
    );
  }
}

class TestClassWithAppCloser with AppCloser {}
```

All that said, IMO such a test is not very useful since it duplicates all of the logic of the code being tested.